# Finding And Removing Duplicates from text file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a huge text file in which a large number of duplication are occurred. The duplications are as follows.

Total Posts 16

Pin Code = GFDHG
TITLE = Shop Signs/Projection Signs/Industrial Signage/Restaurant signs/Menu Boards&Box in London
DATE = 12-09-2012
Tracking Key # 85265E712050-15207427406854753

Total Posts 16

Pin Code = GFDHG
TITLE = Shop Signs/Projection Signs/Industrial Signage/Restaurant signs/Menu Boards&Box in London
DATE = 12-09-2012
Tracking Key # 85265E712050-15207427406854753

Total Posts 2894

Pin Code = GFDHG
TITLE = Shop Signs/Projection Signs/Industrial Signage/Restaurant signs/Menu Boards&Box in London
DATE = 15-09-2012
Tracking Key # 85265E712050-152797637654753

Total Posts 2894

Pin Code = GFDHG
TITLE = Shop Signs/Projection Signs/Industrial Signage/Restaurant signs/Menu Boards&Box in London
DATE = 15-09-2012
Tracking Key # 85265E712050-152797637654753

and so on upto 4000 total posts are there in this text file. I want that my program match the total post 6 to all total post that occurred in file and where find the duplicate , then programatically remove that duplicate and also delete the next 7 lines of that duplicate. Thank you

Comment: So where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want that my program match Total Posts 6 to next Total Posts 6 and remove the 2nd one and the next 5 lines preceding to second one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the formatting is consistent (i.e. each logged event in the file uses 6 total lines of text), then if you're looking to remove duplicates from the file you just need to do something like this:

```
Sub DupClean(ByVal fpath As String) 'fpath is the FULL file path, i.e. C:\Users\username\Documents\filename.txt
        Dim OrigText As String = ""
        Dim CleanText As String = ""
        Dim CText As String = ""
        Dim SReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fpath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim TxtLines As New List(Of String)
        Dim i As Long = 0
        Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Left(fpath, fpath.Length - 4) & "_clean.txt", False) 'to overwrite the text inside the same file simply use StreamWriter(fpath)

        Try
            'Read in the text
            OrigText = SReader.ReadToEnd

            'Parse the text at new lines to allow selecting groups of 6 lines
            TxtLines.AddRange(Split(OrigText, Chr(10))) 'may need to change the Chr # to look for depending on if 10 or 13 is used when the file is generated
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Encountered an error while reading in the text file contents and parsing them. Details: " & ex.Message, vbOKOnly, "Read Error")
            End
        End Try

        Try
            'Now we iterate through blocks of 6 lines 
            Do While i < TxtLines.Count
                'Set CText to the next 6 lines of text
                CText = TxtLines.Item(i) & Chr(10) & TxtLines.Item(i + 1) & Chr(10) & TxtLines.Item(i + 2) & Chr(10) & TxtLines.Item(i + 3) & Chr(10) & TxtLines.Item(i + 4) & Chr(10) & TxtLines.Item(i + 5)

                'Check if CText is already present in CleanText
                If Not (CleanText.Contains(CText)) Then
                    'Add CText to CleanText
                    If CleanText.Length = 0 Then
                        CleanText = CText
                    Else
                        CleanText = CleanText & Chr(10) & CText
                    End If
                End If 'else the text is already present and we don't need to do anything

                i = i + 6
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Encountered an error while running cleaning duplicates from the read in text. The application was on the " & i & "-th line of text when the following error was thrown: " & ex.Message, _
                   vbOKOnly, "Comparison Error")
            End
        End Try

        Try
            'Write out the clean text
            writer.Write(CleanText)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Encountered an error writing the cleaned text. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "The cleaned text was " & CleanText, vbOKOnly, "Write Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

If the format isn't consistent you'll need to get fancier and define rules to tell which lines to add to CText on any given pass through the loop, but without context I wouldn't be able to give you any ideas as to what those may be.